# I have installed prestashop,but facing some problem..?

Tags: prestashop

I have installed prestashop but I can see its back end web page and can login into it but front end shop page is not opening up in my browser and it is showing error.I dont know what is the reason?

Have I made a mistake in understanding prestashop..???Is it to be installed with some other CMS or it is self sufficient ? I have no other file except prestashop files in my web directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not allow URL rewriting. Contact your host to find out what you need to do in order to allow it. Additionally, you can visit the [PrestaShop forums](http://www.prestashop.com/forums) for help on this issue and many others.

Source: [PrestaShop Bug Tracker](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-2700)